# Model Spring MVC

Tags: base-de-datos, botón, spring-mvc, controller, model

estoy realizando un proyecto con Spring mvc y tengo la siguiente duda. ¿Cómo puedo modificar/actualizar un atributo del Model cada vez que pulso un botón sin recargar la página? En este atributo guardo una variable que modifico desde el controlador y necesito guardar en bbdd.

HTML:

```
<a th:href="@{/pulsar"><input type="button" value="Elegir" /></a>
```

CONTROLLER

```
@ResponseBody
@RequestMapping(value = "/pulsar", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public void elegir(Model model) {
        counter++;
        model.addAttribute("counter", counter); 
       //Lo guardo en base de datos cada vez que se pulsa el botón
}
```

Muchas gracias.

Comment: Coloca tu codigo, para que puedan ayudarte.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El Model es una variable cuyo ciclo de vida tiene validez durante la ejecución del servlet. Sirve para reemplazar los valores que tenga en la plantilla que uses (JSP, Thymeleaf, etc.)

Una vez devuelta la respuesta al cliente HTTP, el Model se envía al recolector de basura. Es por esto por lo que no podrás modificar el Model una vez se ha mostrado la página ya que ese objeto ha dejado de existir.

Eso no quiere decir que no se pueda hacer lo que quieres, solo que lo tienes que enfocar desde otra perspectiva.

Si no quieres recurrir a frameworks de reactividad tipo Angular, Vue, etc, lo que puedes hacer cuando quieras modificar un dato es crear una operación en un controlador que reciba los parámetros necesarios para modificar tus tablas de la base de datos.

Una vez modificadas, ese método te devolvería los datos que tengas que modificar en la vista para que el usuario vea reflejado el cambio. Estos datos modificados irían en un Model, pero fíjate que es un nuevo Model asociado a la segunda petición que has hecho al servidor web, siendo la primera la petición de renderizado de la página web, y la segunda la petición de modificación del dato. Esta segunda petición la tendrás que hacer por AJAX para que no haya recarga en la página.

Te dejo un ejemplo con jQuery, aunque podría hacerse con JavaScript puro o usando alguna otra librería específica:

```
$("#miboton").click(function(){
  $.ajax({url: "/incrementar", success: function(result){
    $("#micontador").html(result);
  }});
});
```

Esto lo que haría sería que cuando se pulse el botón con id "miboton", se haga una petición al controlador que tengas registrado en "/incrementar". Y que cuando recibas el nuevo valor, se escriba en un contendor con id "micontador".

En tu controlador te tendrás que encargar de incrementar ese valor en la base de datos y devolver el número que quieras mostrar en la vista.

Si prefieres usar alguno de estos frameworks puedes hacer una reingeniería para que tus métodos en lugar de devolver HTML devuelva datos en JSON o algún otro formato similar, y tener un modelo de datos esta vez en tu JavaScript en vez de en tu backend Spring y aprovechar esta reactividad para que las vistas se actualicen automáticamente en función de los datos que tengas en tu modelo JavaScript.

Comment: Muchas gracias, creo que me ha aclarado bastante. Pero a raíz de esto me surge otra duda...¿cómo realizo una petición por AJAX para que llame a un método del controlador?

Comment: @Anonimo he editado la respuesta y añadido un ejemplo de llamada con jQuery.

Comment: Muchas gracias. Me está siendo de gran ayuda. La pulsación del botón si la coge pero me salta este error al intentar llamar al método del controller: WARN 11884 --- [nio-8080-exec-3] .w.s.m.s.DefaultHandlerExceptionResolver : Resolved [org.springframework.web.method.annotation.MethodArgumentTypeMismatchException: Failed to convert value of type 'java.lang.String' to required type 'int'; nested exception is java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "incrementar"]. ¿Alguna idea del motivo?

Comment: @Anonimo llegados a este punto diria que lo mejor sería hacer una pregunta nueva añadiendo el código del controlador para ver que puede estar pasando.

Comment: SOLUCIONADO! Gracias!! Lo único...¿cómo puedo coger el valor que devuelve la función y en el html hacer un switch con ese valor? Porque como devuelve un Integer, lo que hace es poner el número en ese div. Pero necesito que dependiendo de ese valor muestre un elemento del div o otro.

Comment: Por favor hazlo como pregunta nueva porque esta ya se está haciendo un lío con tantas ediciones. En la pregunta indica por favor el html que tengas para ver la estructura de los elementos que quieres mostrar u ocultar.

Comment: gracias, ya hice otra pregunta: Cómo acceder en html thymeleaf a un valor devuelto por una función en javascript